# Absolute positioned nav arrow issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having an issue where my left navigation arrow for a portfolio viewer I'm using is moving with the size of the window and I can't figure out how to contain it within my div and stay stationary. The plugin that I'm using is called "Portfoliojs"

Here is the link to the page that I'm having the issue on: http://bopratt.com/bopratt/test/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element with position: absolute is relative to the page, or the next highest relatively positioned element.

You can add position: relative to #bomain which will make the position: absolute in .gallery-arrow-right relative to that div instead of to the page (and not always stay left: x distance from the left edge of the page)

```
#bomain {
    position: relative;
    /* other stuff */
}
```

you will also need to adjust the css on .gallery-arrow-right (something like top: 0 and left: 870px)